# ресайз картинки

Tags: html, css

Есть картинка . Как реализовать что бы при увеличении/уменьшении и любом разрешении экрана картинка всегда оставалась того же размера в том же положении

Comment: задать ей width и height

Comment: так задайте ей размер и положение